# no output on server using django

Tags: python, django, linux, ubuntu-10.04

my views.py file code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

from django.template import loader, RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponse
#from skey import find_root_tags, count, sorting_list
from search.models import Keywords
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response as rr

def front_page(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' :
        from skey import find_root_tags, count, sorting_list
        str1 = request.POST['word'] 
        fo = open("/home/pooja/Desktop/xml.txt","r")

        for i in range(count.__len__()):

            file = fo.readline()
            file = file.rstrip('\n')
            find_root_tags(file,str1,i) 

            list.append((file,count[i]))

        sorting_list(list)

        for name, count1 in list:
            s = Keywords(file_name=name,frequency_count=count1)
            s.save()

            fo.close()

        list1 = Keywords.objects.all()
        t = loader.get_template('search/results.html')
        c = Context({'list1':list1,})

        return HttpResponse(t.render(c))

    else :  
        str1 = ''
        list = []
        template = loader.get_template('search/front_page.html')
        c = RequestContext(request)
        response = template.render(c)
        return HttpResponse(response) 

 <body BGCOLOR = #9ACD32">
<ul> 
{ % for l in list1 %}
        <li> {{l.file_name}}, {{l.frquency_count}}</li>
{ % endfor %}
</ul>

</body>
```

on running my app on server, it asks me for the word  and redirects to results.html and is giving this output:

```
{ % for l in list1 %}

- List item,

{ % endfor %}
```

why is this happening, where am I mistaking?whereas values are getting stored in table , I checked it through admin page , then why is'it displaying?
Please help.

Comment: please anyone help me in this problem , what is that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ % for l in list1 %}
```

should be

```
{% for l in list1 %}
```

and

```
{ % endfor %}
```

should be

```
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: As a side note: I've seen this same code snippet quite a few times these last days, and for a couple things I see I suspect I'll see it again pretty soon. I don't mean to be rude, I understand we all have to start somewhere someday and that it's not obvious, and I know I still have a huge lot to learn myself - but seriously, most of your latests questions were about problems you could have solved by yourself with a bit more googling, reading and dedication.

Answer (score 0):

never put a space between '{' and '%'